# Which BuildContext do we have to choose? Inner or outer one?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code is a trivial example for illustration purpose only.

- `Scaffold.of(...)` cannot use the outmost `BuildContext` because of a well-known reason. That is why I have to wrap `Scaffold.of(...)` with `Build` widget.
- `Navigator.push(...)` invoked in the `Build` widget can use `BuildContext` provided by either the `Build` widget itself or the outmost one.

## Question

Is there any difference between invoking `Navigator.push(inner)` and invoking `Navigator.push(outer)`? If yes, which one should we choose?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'ThirdPage.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext outer) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Second Page')),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (inner) => RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Going  to 3rd page...'),
            onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(inner).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Going to 3rd page...'),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Go to 3rd page',
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                        inner, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ThirdPage())))))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please use inner build context!

Comment: @RohitSoni Is there any scientific reason?

Comment: Yes, because your all inner widget are child of builder widgets.

Comment: And also you can use parent context (outer)

Comment: The inner build context is passed down from the outer one. It is best to use the inner one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A context is nothing but a reference to the location of a Widget within the widget tree.

Specifically a context is the part of Widgets tree where the Widget is attached to this tree.

A context only belongs to one widget.

For any given 'Widget' with children, the context of that 'Widget' will become the parent context of the children contexts. Contexts are chained and form parent-children relationship.

Routes contexts are tied to the Application. If you Navigate to second screen from first screen, the only way for the second screen to know anything about the context of the first screen is to obtain it from the first screen as parameter of Navigator.of(context).push( ... ).

The inner is deeper in widget tree so it would hold more context that the outer.

Comment: Thank you. I have to wait for a couple of hours or days before accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the use case if it is actually relevant which `BuildContext` you use. The `BuildContext` you have access to in the `build` method of a widget, is the one which has been passed as a parameter of this method. This one has been provided by the nearest ancestor which called this widget. It therefore holds the information available since then. Thats for example the reason you need to make use of a `Builder` widget as you pointed out in your question, since the `Scaffold` is being created in the current build method and the passed `BuildContext` does not know this yet. By using the `Builder` widget we essentially slip another widget in between which will have the `BuildContext` where the `Scaffold` has been inserted in the widget tree.

So you generally have to ask yourself: if you want to access anything related to `BuildContext`, is it important to be the "most updated one" (the inner one)? For the `Scaffold` example yes, but for the `Navigator` one no, since the actual `Navigator` widget has been inserted into the widget tree by your `MatrialApp` widget (which is pretty close to the root of your widget tree) and probably any `BuildContext` you reference knows this already and will find the `Navigator` instance with `Navigator.of`.

Again it always depends on the use case, but asking yourself what I just mentioned might help you later on!